# C Criteria API подзапрос с IN (select * from a where id in (select form b)

Tags: java

Привет. Для меня понимание Criteria API пока трудно даётся. Помогите решить, если не сложно.

Имеется таблица юзеров содержащая город юзера.
Имеется также справочная таблица городов, где указана страна города.

Такой запрос делает то, что мне нужно:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE birth_location IN
(SELECT id FROM city WHERE country_id = 2)
```

Готового решения не нашёл.
Вот кусок моего кода для поиска просто по городу:

```
if (searchParams.getBirthCity() != null) {
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(User_.birthLocation), searchParams.getBirthCity()));
}
```

Comment: В данном случае IN SUBSELECT не нужен. Ни в SQL, ни в JPQL, ни в Criteria API. Всё делается обычным JOIN. В JPA даже проще чем SQL получается, если классы сделаны правильно. Но Ваших классов не видно. Что тут конкретно посоветуешь?

Comment: Если всё как надо, то просто продолжайте продвигаться по цепочке (path-у) c помощью get от user до country:
`predicates.add(cb.equals(root.get(User_.birthLocation).get(City_.country)), searchParams.getBirthCountry()))`

Comment: Я как раз вернулся, потому что понял, что есть ещё вариант того же запроса с join:  `select * from usert
join city
on usert.birth_location=city.id
where country_id = 2`

Comment: Попробую ваш вариант с гетами и отпишусь

Comment: @banme Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае IN SUBSELECT не нужен. Ни в SQL, ни в JPQL, ни в Criteria API. Всё делается обычным JOIN. В JPA даже проще чем SQL получается, если классы сделаны правильно.
Просто продолжайте продвигаться по цепочке (path-у) c помощью get от user до city:

```
predicates.add(cb.equals(root.get(User_.birthLocation).get(City_.country)), searchParams.getBirthCountry()))
```

Если нужно искать именно по id, то пройти ещё дальше, до country:

```
predicates.add(cb.equals(root.get(User_.birthLocation).get(City_.country).get(Country_.id)), searchParams.getBirthCountryId()))
```

JPA в этом случае сам автоматически применяет все необходимые JOIN-ы.